# What does ISIC option "-t" mean?

Tags: linux, ip, router, vulnerabilities, vulnerability

As I already found out, ISIC tool has an option "-t" only for tcpsic or tcpsic6 and it means percentage of packets with wrong checksum.
In `tcpsic` case my router works fine.
But when Ive been testing my router with 
`isic -s rand -d 192.168.10.20 -t 100 -p 1000000 -r 10` 
I've found a vulnerability on my router. 
If I could know what `-t` does for `isic` I could figure out this problem on my router.

Comment: Did you read the man page?

Comment: of course! and there is no words about this option for isic, only for tcpsic

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by checking the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/isic). Sadly, it is ambiguous at best.

> **Percentage Options**
>
> These options are defined to all but esic. …
>
> …
>
> -t
>
> > Available for tcpsic and tcpsic6 only, the percentage of TCP packets with bad TCP checksum.
>
> …

So the `-t` option applies to `isic` per the "defined to all but esic" part. Yet it also does not apply, per the "for tcpsic and tcpsic6 only" part.

When faced with such ambiguity, check the [source](http://isic.sourceforge.net/).

The source for `tcpsic` includes:

> `while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "hd:s:r:m:k:Dp:V:F:I:u:T:t:vx:")) != EOF){`
>
> …
>
> `case 't'`
>
> `TCPCksm = atof(optarg);`
>
> `break;`

And the source for `isic` includes:

> `while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "hd:I:s:r:m:k:Dp:V:F:vx:")) != EOF) {`

and no `case` statement for `-t`.

## Conclusion

- The `-t` option is ignored for `isic`.
- The part of the man page that says "These options are defined to all but esic" is incorrect.

Comment: @DougDegen Yeah, Great! There were many contradictions, that's why I asked.
Thank you!